# MAX php from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query and I want find MAX value of a column with the MAX in PHP.

Query is like this

```
Select  m.name, count(*) as album_sold
          from Musicians_ as M, albumproducer as A
          where (M.ssn=A.ssn )
          group by m.ssn;
```

This query is made by 2 array, one is made up by name and the other is made up with copy of album sold.

This is the table in xml form

```
-<ROW>
<name>George Martin</name>
<album_sold>2</album_sold>
</ROW>

-<ROW>
<name>Ron Wood</name>
<album_sold>1</album_sold>
</ROW>
</DATA>
```

I want to count and print the column of album_sold and the name as well with MAX in php, but I don't know how. Any ideas?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What do you want to say with " in PHP " ? how did you store result from request ?

Comment: There's no PHP code here. (fyi, you could also use MAX() in your query)

Comment: I want to print the maximum value of the albums sold with the relative name of the producer, but the maximum must be found with the php code starting from the query in sql. it is an educational exercise.

Comment: When you retrieve the first row, store the value from the relevant column in a variable. Each time you retrieve subsequent rows, compare the stored MAX to the newly retrieved column and update as required. Use a `while...` construct to retrieve rows, and an `<condition> ? <do if true> : <do if false>` to perform the comparison

Answer (score 0):

You could select only the max value form db  using limit 1 order by desc

```
  Select  m.name, count(*) as album_stampati
  from Musicians_ as M
  INNER JOIN albumproducer as A ON M.ssn=A.ssn
  group by m.ssn 
  order by album_stampati desc limit 1
```

Comment: thanks, but I do not want to find the maximum through sql code but with php code starting from the aforementioned query.

Comment: then instead of limit  1 don't limit and use the first ..........................